# Replace multiline with single line in a string+Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to replace all multiplines with single line in a string in javascript but none is working . Below is my code :

```js
var str=inputList.replace(/\n/gm,"\n");
```

input e.g.

```
abc,def <3 newlines>


xyz <1 newline>
opp
```

Expected output:

```
abc,def <1 newline>
xyz
opp
```

Actual output:

```
abc,def<3 newlines>


xyz<1 newline>
opp
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are replacing every occurrence of one `\n` _with_ one `\n` …

Comment: Your goal is very unclear, and the fact you misuse the code snippet feature (it's supposed to help test your code) doesn't help

Comment: `var str=inputList.replace(/\n+/gm,"\n");` ???? I am confused with the final output... So if there is only one, than you replace it with no line breaks?

Comment: Try `var str=inputList.replace(/\n{2,}/g,"\n");`. If that does not work, try also `var str=inputList.replace(/(\r?\n|<br\s*\/?>){2,}/g,"\n");`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are matching just one and replacing it with one. I believe if you just add the `+` after the `\n` to match one or more. If you do not want to match just one use `{2,}` to match two or more.

```
var str=inputList.replace(/\n+/g,"\n");
                             ^
```

or

```
var str=inputList.replace(/\n{2,}/g,"\n");
                             ^^^^
```

Answer (score 3):

(Edit : simplified version thanks to stribizhev)

If you are trying to replace two or more `\n` with one, try this :

```
var str = inputList.replace(/\n{2,}/gm,"\n");
```

{2,} means 2 or more

Comment: There is no need escaping `\n` as `\\n` and the capturing group is redundant here. And `/m` modifier is also redundant.

Comment: so what do you suggest? `/\n{2,}/gm` also seems to work, if that's what you mean

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing `\n` with `\n` in your code.

Instead do:

```
var str = inputList.replace(/\n/gm, "");
```

Comment: I believe OP is trying to replace `TWO \n or more` with one `\n`.

Comment: Why use `/m` modifier?

Comment: @JeremyThille I believe we should wait to have a proper question before to guess the need